# How to substract in one array

Tags: php, arrays, loops, compare

I am still beginner.
I want to subtract a value in an array, then I want to compare values. I have an array, the values are not known, depend on the result of a function.

Example :

```
$value = [5,8,13,15];
```

I want to subtract each value and save it in an array. Example :

```
8-5 = 3
13-8 = 5
15-13 = 2
```

then I want to compare each value (3, 5, 2), which one is bigger.
Please help me. Thank you before.

Comment: What have you tried doing so far?

Comment: Do you want to substract all of them? Like 15-13 & 15-8 & 15-5 etc

Comment: @ÜmitAparı just substract with one index before. sorry bad english

Comment: Check my answer @Hery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$value = [5,18,13,15];
sort($value); //to not get negative results
$loop = 0;
$results = array();
while ($loop < count($value))
{
    if ($loop == 0)
    {
        $loop++;
    }
    else 
    {
        $firstval = $value[$loop];
        $secondval = $value[$loop-1];
        $results[] = intval($firstval) - intval($secondval);
        $loop++; 
    }
}
sort($results);
$thebiggestkey = $results[count($results)-1];
```

This should do it for you

Comment: If you are ok with getting negative results or don't want the $value array to be sorted from smaller to bigger you can remove the sort($value); code

Answer (score 0):

A small example with Indexes and Array, if you here is wishes it you can use Foreach to subtract all that there is in the Array
( http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php )

```
    $value = [5,8,3,13,15];

    $rep = $value[0] - $value[1];
    //5 - 8

    echo $rep;
    //return -3
```